# SNMP Generator: cannot find OID to walk in a specific mib

Tags: generator, snmp, mib, oid

I want to use the snmmp exporter for prometheus. For the Configuration of this exporter you should use the snmp generator. To use this you have to configurate a yaml file where you put in the oid you want to run. To get the some mibs i downloaded some with:

```
apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
```

I used some oids from those mibs and i worked totaly fine. Now i wanted to use some specific oids. So I downloaded the mib file for it and placed in the same directory where the mib files are located (/usr/share/snmp/mibs).
But when i execute the generater it says:

[image]

I am also able to find the oid in the mib file:

[image]

The only strange thing is that the mib file is shown as an executable (is green highlighted in the -ls command and has a *), and the other mib files are not.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.01 and the snmp_generator V 0.20.
I Hope someone has a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

snDownloadParamsError is OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.4196.1.1.2.100.1.5.1.7.0, so it seems that you use Module SN-OSM-PRIV-MIB.
This module could be found here
https://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Html/S/SN-OSM-PRIV-MIB.php
Also you could learn from this site that it has a number of Imported modules:
RFC-1215, RFC1155-SMI, RFC1213-MIB, RFC-1212.
You need all of them.